# Android spinner gets values from file

Tags: android, list, arraylist, spinner, text-files

I have a problem with android spinner. I'm trying to get spinner drop down values from a List that reads its values from file.. 
I have 2 spinners. When first spinner value is selected then second spinner displays the corresponding values.
At the moment I just read spinner values from a List that I made, but I want to read them from a text file.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String foodCategory = String.valueOf(spFoodCategory.getSelectedItem());

    if(foodCategory.contentEquals("Milk products")) {   
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("Joghurt R2.2% 100g - 76 kcal");
          list.add("Cheese R24% - 332 kcal");
          list.add("Milk 100ml - 56 kcal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spFoodProduct.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }

    if(foodCategory.contentEquals("Meat and fish products")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Chicken 100g - 142 kcal");
        list.add("Minced meat R20% 100g - 246 kcal");
        list.add("Herring 100g - 235 kcal");
        list.add("Ham 100g - 130kcal");
        list.add("Egg 100g - 135 kcal");
        list.add("Bacon 100g - 301 kcal");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spFoodProduct.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the files you want in the `assets` folder then read them line by line and add to your lists.

Here's how to read from assets

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
InputStream txt = getAssets().open("file.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(txt, "UTF-8"));
String str;

while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
  list.add(str);
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried something similar, but it gives me an error and suggests to use Try-Catch around everywhere, so when I put all suggested Try-Catches and when I try to run it on my emulator then it closes my application immediately, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't something else that led your application to close immediately? 

try following [this post](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/05/open-read-file-from-assets.html) to read file from assets

Comment: I got it fixed. I just had to make it as another method, not inside my existing method, because in another method I can use 'throws Exception' which I couldn't use in my existing method. Thank you! :)